# filter object and assign property values to array?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have a ko object which has some properties. I only need the value of the ItemName property.

is it possible to filter this object and get the ItemName Property value and push it into an array.

```
items":[{"ItemID":1,"ItemName":"Asia","ItemLevel":0,"ItemParentID":0},
        {"ItemID":2,"ItemName":"Europe","ItemLevel":1,"ItemParentID":0},
        {"ItemID":3,"ItemName":"Africa","ItemLevel":2,"ItemParentID":0}]
```

so that we end up with the following:

```
array[0] = "Asia"
array[1] = "Europe"
array[2] = "Africa"

ko.utils.arrayFilter(items(), function(item) {
            return item.ItemName();
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arrayMap

```
items":[{"ItemID":1,"ItemName":"Asia","ItemLevel":0,"ItemParentID":0},
        {"ItemID":2,"ItemName":"Europe","ItemLevel":1,"ItemParentID":0},
        {"ItemID":3,"ItemName":"Africa","ItemLevel":2,"ItemParentID":0}]

var array = ko.utils.arrayMap(items, function(item) {
    return item.ItemName;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) with an include mapping to only copy over the field you want:

```
var mapping = {
    'include': ["ItemName""]
}
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(items, mapping);
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote almost right code. Just replace `arrayFilter` with `arrayMap`:

```
ko.utils.arrayMap(items(), function(item) {
            return item.ItemName();
        });
```